# How to use match() method when I have a variable dynamically with case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have case insensitive strings to be compared like,

`const a = 'b'`

`const c = 'B'`

So for comparing these, I used the `match()` method, but it works for static strings like we can use / for doing case insensitive comparison.

Eg. `a.match(/b/)`, but I need to do it dynamically like
if I have a variable, **test1 = 'b'** and **test2 = 'B'**, but when doing like this `test1.match(/test2/)` it gets "test2" as string but I need the value('B') in it.

[image: As I have tried like the following image]

Comment: try making an array of possible search options, and then combine thoughs using a loop to create a custom dynamic regex pattern using the values from the array, then use the new custom dynamic pattern to be placed into your `match` function

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `RegExp` constructor to make a dynamic regular expression that depends on the variable's value.

```js
function isMatch(str, testCase) {
  var rgx = new RegExp(testCase);
  return str.match(rgx);
}

console.log(isMatch("b", "b"));
console.log(isMatch("b", "B"));
console.log(isMatch("hello world", "hello"));
console.log(isMatch("hello world", "hi"));
```

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info.

Comment: Yes but this one is case sensitive, is there a way to do for case insensitive?

Comment: Add the `i` flag like this `var rgx = new RegExp(testCase, 'i');`. I've updated the answer with the Mdn link for more info.